# How we can integrate javascript code in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I working in Reactjs and using Nextjs,I am trying to integrate "index.html" to
"index.js", in bottom of "index.html" i have following javascript code,And i want to know
that this code should be move in which file ? And How ?

```
<script language = "text/Javascript"> 
  cleared[0] = cleared[1] = cleared[2] = 0; //set a cleared flag for each field
  function clearField(t){                   //declaring the array outside of the
  if(! cleared[t.id]){                      // function makes it static and global
      cleared[t.id] = 1;  // you could use true and false, but that's more typing
      t.value='';         // with more chance of typos
      t.style.color='#fff';
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you have your react code in `index.js`, and the code you show in the question in `index.html`?

Comment: This script will likely interfere with react.

Comment: @OliverRadini: You are right, rest of my code in "index.js" but i want to know that where should i put this javascript code and how

Comment: @evolutionxbox kindly tell me how can i use this code and which file

Comment: You should convert the script to React code directly. However, it's not clear what the script is meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your react code will exist within some global context; in the browser, that'd typically be `window`.

If you assign something to that context, as you do with your `clearField` function, then it should be available to React.

[Hopefully you can see this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-panna-mjeyh6?file=/public/index.html). In `index.html`:

```html
    <script>
      function getTheThing() {
        return "This is the thing";
      }
    </script>
```

In `app.js`:

```
export default function App() {
  const thing = window.getTheThing();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {thing}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the rendered output, `thing` is rendered as the result of `getTheThing` defined in `index/html`

There can be many variations with this, so without knowing the exact situation it's rather hard to say

Comment: Actually i dont want to use "index.html" i just want to use "index.html" code in my React(Nextjs) project,Hope you understand my point

Comment: @Vyom would it not work to just copy and paste the code into one of the files which holds your react code?